# How to find x,y of the lower left corner of a rotated rectangle

Tags: php, math, geometry

I have a point x,y of the upper left corner of a rectangle.

Known values are:

- x,y (upper left corner)
- width/height of rectangle
- rotation

How can I find the x,y point of the lower left corner

[image]

Comment: Is the point of origin on top-left?

Comment: Are you aware that answered questions assume some kind of feedback?

Comment: @MBo i think this is a different question, and I am just about to try out your answer to the other question

Comment: Yes, question might be different, but I'd want to know if technique in that topic works (suitable and understandable) in your case.

Comment: @Pavitra point of origin is the center of the rectangle

Comment: Center of rotation is the center of the rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

`x - height*sin(theta)` and `y-height*cos(theta)` will be the required `(x,y)` if `theta` is the rotation